# php execution changes array format

Tags: php, json

My php file, receives two variables `$addNodeProperty` and `$addNodeValue` and adds those to an array. Unfortunately the format is changing during this process and I can´t figure out why.

The array, **before** the php execution:

```
"properties": [
                {
                    "property": "CPU",
                    "value": "4"
                },
                {
                    "property": "RAM",
                    "value": "16 GB"
                },
                {
                    "property": "HDD",
                    "value": "2 TB"
                }
              ]
```

The array, **after** the php execution. You will notice the object numbers in front of the first three entries. Those I need to remove, it should look like the array before the execution with the added object:

```
  "properties": {
                "0": {
                    "property": "CPU",
                    "value": "4"
                },
                "1": {
                    "property": "RAM",
                    "value": "16 GB"
                },
                "2": {
                    "property": "HDD",
                    "value": "2 TB"
                },
                {
                "property": "Neue Eigenschaft",
                "value": "Neuer Wert"
                }
            }
```

The php I am using:

```
<?php

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    $nodeId = ($_POST['nodeId']);
    $addNodeProperty = ($_POST['addNodeProperty']);
    $addNodeValue = ($_POST['addNodeValue']);

    $json = file_get_contents("../data/data.json");
    $data = json_decode($json, true);

    $nodes = $data['nodes'];

    $nodeIdInArray = array_search($nodeId, array_column($nodes, 'id'));

    $nodes[$nodeIdInArray]['properties']['property'] = $addNodeProperty;
    $nodes[$nodeIdInArray]['properties']['value'] = $addNodeValue;

    $nodes = array_values($nodes);
    $data['nodes'] = $nodes;

    $json = json_encode($data);

    file_put_contents("../data/data.json", $json);

?>
```

Comment: Why do you need it removed? Its the same array. Both in JS and in PHP, arrays start with an index of 0 if you don't specify a key.

Comment: @Qirel in case I leave the keys, the D3.js code isn´t working anymore. Means no graph will be visualized.

Answer (score -1):

Simple Arrays can not holds keys, that is why it is converting it to associative array.

If you still need like the 1st code

```
"properties": [
                {
                    "property": "CPU",
                    "value": "4"
                },
                {
                    "property": "RAM",
                    "value": "16 GB"
                },
                {
                    "property": "HDD",
                    "value": "2 TB"
                }
              ]
```

then you should use something like this:

```
... ['properties'][] = ["property"=> "Neue Eigenschaft", "value"=> "Neuer Wert"]
```

Comment: This is outright false. If you don't specify the keys, PHP will assign it a key - starting from 0. So what OP is seeing, is just that its assigning keys -- because all elements in arrays needs a key, otherwise how can you access specific elements?

Comment: No, See this: ` "2": {
                    "property": "HDD",
                    "value": "2 TB"
                },
                {
                "property": "Neue Eigenschaft",
                "value": "Neuer Wert"
                }`
two type of keys one is indexed int values and other string values. So to make it consistent hence above code.